# Do I have to import a class that is in the same package but in different folders?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have some classes that are located in `classes/com/scja/exam/tutorial/planets` on the filesystem. I'm trying to compile a file that is located in `classes/com/scja/exam/tutorial/`. Do I have to manually import this ? I'm trying to compile using this command:

> javac -d classes -cp classes/com/scja/exam/tutorial/planets/:.
>   src/com/scjaexam/tutorial/GreetingsUniverse.java

It seems like java cannot find the classes this file needs.

Comment: Try it. It might work

Comment: `import`.  (You do, of course, need to have the class properly located in your classpath.)

Comment: First CD to the "root" of your package.

Comment: The paths you've specified suggest *different* packages. The directory paths should be parallel to the packages.

Comment: @HotLicks. Even importing I get the same error.

Comment: What is the package name?  If it's `com.scja....` then CD to "classes" and compile from there.

Comment: (Note that the individual files must be in the "appropriate" place for their packages.  `com.scja.exam.tutorial.Gizmo` should be in com/scja/exam/tutorial/.  `com.scja.exam.tutorial.planets.Whozit` should be in com/scja/exam/tutorial/planets.)

Comment: @HotLicks, I've compiled the classes the file needs. Now I'm trying to compile the .java that is located in classes/com/scja/exam/tutorial/. This .java uses some classes that are located in classes/com/scja/exam/tutorial/planets.

Comment: You need to add the compiled classes to the classpath *with the proper paths*.  Your `-cp` should probably be just `-cp classes`, since likely the classes you're after are in package com.scja.exam.tutorial.planets.

Comment: @HotLicks. Tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to tell us the package names of each class that can't be found, and where it's located in the directory structure.

Comment: (Back up a bit and understand that Java is not "broken", but rather you're confused.  This is a confusing topic, especially for the neophyte, so it's no shame to be confused, so long as you don't let the confusion blind you.)

Comment: Check this simple tutorial about CLASSPATH., http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html.

Comment: Ok. I got 3 files within package com.scja.exam.tutorial.planets package and one in com.scja.exam.tutorial package. I've compiled the 3 files. Now I have to compile the package in com.scja.exam.tutorial package that uses those classes.

Comment: **WHERE ARE THE FILES LOCATED IN THE FILE SYSTEM??**

Comment: the classes or the .java ? They are in different folders.

Comment: When I imported the files it worked!

Comment: Both. Edit your original question and add at the bottom a list of directories.  And beneath each directory, insert the identities of the files in that directory, listing their package name (as specified with a `package` directive), their class name, and whether .java or .class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Understand that when Java searches for a class named `aaa.bbb.ccc.MyClass`, it searches each directory in the classpath for a directory named "aaa".  Finding one, it will search that directory for "bbb", then, if that's found "ccc", then actually look for "MyClass.class".  If you make your classpath `-cp aaa/bbb/ccc` then Java will look there, find no "aaa", and give up.

Comment: Yes, it does not matter where it is as long as it is a part of your path. I have added a jar with a package in it to a Netbeans project, and all I needed to do was import the package as if it was part of the project itself.

Answer (score 2):

A class in a package must import classes it uses (without using their fully qualified name) that are not in the same package (an not in java.lang). The directories where the classes are stored must match the packages, but you could have several root directories (or jars) containing the classes.

Your command doesn't work because you put the directory of a package (`classes/com/scja/exam/tutorial/planets/`) in the classpath, instead of putting the root directory (`classes`).

Comment: Try to adopt a rigorous approach. Make sure the directories match with the packages. Make sur to place java files in a different tree than the class files. And when something doesn't work, read the error message. Try to understand it. And if you don't, describe your problem clearly, by explaining which files are in which locations, which exact command you type, from where, and which is the exact and complete error message you get. Simply saying "it doesn't work" doesn't help. It works if you do it correctly.

Comment: It worked for me. The problems was that I had to include the classes. I thought I only had to do it during compilation.